# ECONNREFUSED postgresql with nodejs when build docker

Tags: database, postgresql, docker, nestjs

I'm build an web using NestJs, using PostgreSQL and using TypeORM as ORM. When I run `docker compose up` it starts and said that

```
database system is ready to accept connections
```

but after that it can't connect to database

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.29.0.2:5444
```

Here is the docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5444:5444" 
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: asset_dis

  app:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: asset_dis
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5444/asset_dis
```

Could someone help me with this (this is the first time I use docker)

Comment: Where do you tell postgres to run on port 5444? All you've told docker is to expose the container's port `5444`to the machine's port `5444`

Comment: PostgreSQL's normal port is 5432, not 5444, and this needs to be the port number in `DATABASE_URL` and the second number in the database's `ports:`.